# Will threads be faster if each gets their own copy of a read only array

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

If I have a number of threads that each do some calculations based on a joint read only array, will it be faster if I provide each array with a separate copy of that array. For example, assume `X` is an array with 
 numbers between 0 and 1 and thread n computes `sin(nX)` (entrywise). Should I create deep copies of `X` to each thread?

Of course I could just try it out, but I will first have to learn how to implement threads in the first place. I am looking to do this in C++, in case it matters.

Comment: If the data is immutable (read-only) then there will be no need for synchronization or locking nor creating temporary read-only local copies - so my initial answer is to say that there's no performance benefits from copying the memory around - the only exception is if you're using NUMA nodes. Additionally, assuming the threads run on the same physical processor chips then if as the threads share the same memory regions then they'll benefit from ideal proximal locality caching: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, there’s no advantage to making per-thread copies of read-only data.  Each CPU will already keep its own copy of recently accessed memory in its cache, and if the data is read-only, the cache won’t ever need to be invalidated by write operations from other CPUs.

The story might be a little different if accessing the purportedly read-only data actually involves hidden write operations, such as updating reference counts if you’re using `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 3):

First off I would like to mention that this may be a good task for CUDA.

With that out of the way, it is unlikely that multiple copies of the same array will help performance. If anything it will worsen performance. If they are read only then there is no need for mutexes, thus they can still read from the same block of memory at the same time. On top of that if each thread gets their own copy, then you have to do a rather slow copy.

Finally, and this is probably the most important yet subtle part, if you have a single block of memory, then the CPU can copy that into its cache which will drastically improve performance.